# Select all columns on an object with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query:

```
var transactions = from t in db.Transactions
                        where t.SellingPrice != 0 
                        select new { t.CommissionPercent, t.SellingPrice };
```

But in reality, I need to avoid using an anonymous type because it is readonly and select all the properties/columns on my "transaction" item.

I would have thought that it would be something like this:

```
var transactions = from t in db.Transactions
                        where t.SellingPrice != 0 
                        select t.SellingPrice, t.CommissionPercent, t.Etc...
```

Or...

```
var transactions = from t in db.Transactions
                        where t.SellingPrice != 0 
                        select t.SellingPrice
                        select t.CommissionPercent
                        select t.Etc...
```

Is there no way to retrieve everything the object has for properties and pass it to the Ienumerable?

Comment: did you try "db.Transactions.Where(m => m.SellingPrice != 0);

Comment: I was constantly getting an error with select t. I restarted visual studio and it seems to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to avoid anonymous types and get everything, why not just return an `IEnumerable` of the original transaction item?

```
var transactions = from t in db.Transactions
                        where t.SellingPrice != 0 
                        select t;
```

Comment: Just select t? What? VS gave me an error when I tried it. Ill have to look at my code, but since others have posted it - surely it must be correct.

Answer (score 19):

In addition, If there is a ***join*** condition between objects, we might get the result using..

```
var result = (from t in db.Transactions
                      join te in db.TransactionsEntries 
                             on t.WorkorderID equals te.WorkorderID                         
             select new { t, te }).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this and it returned the two objects' ToString() methods instead of the objects' columns. I assume the fact that I am using Linq to objects doesn't make a difference?

Answer (score 8):

I believe this would work.

```
var transactions = from t in db.Transactions
                        where t.SellingPrice != 0 
                        select t;
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you want

```
var transactions = db.Transactions.Where(t => t.SellingPrice != 0).ToList();
```

or

```
var transactions = db.Transactions.Where(t => t.SellingPrice != 0).AsEnumerable();
```

if you truly just want an IEnumerable

Comment: @fullNelson this loads all resulting records at once into memory (because of the `ToList` ! depending on how much data it is this might or might not be what you want...

Comment: I wasn't going to put the ToList() on it, but he asked for an IEnumerable.

Comment: @Yahia Its not a large set of data ultimately (1500 records) I need to write a query to patch up some data and I wanted to do it with LINQ as opposed to the alternative. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @deltree, I think `AsEnumerable()` would be better suited than `ToList()` to get and `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
var transactions = from t in db.Transactions
                    where t.SellingPrice != 0 
                    select t;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you "need" to avoid an anonymous type here?

You have the following options:

```
select t
select new { t.CommissionPercent, t.SellingPrice }; 
select new MyCustomDtoClass { CommissionPercent = t.CommissionPercent, SellingPrice  = t.SellingPrice }; //also ok
select new object[] { t.CommissionPercent, t.SellingPrice }
```

The last one is inconvenient to handle. No way around this. Tell us what you want to do.

Comment: Well oddly enough my problem is larger and difficult to post here, but the anonymous type is readonly and i need to be able to update property on it.

Comment: Ok, then go with number 3. Write a custom data transfer object class with auto properties (R# generates that from the anonymous type - press ctrl-shift-r). You can update those properties.

Comment: interesting thought. Ill try it a couple of different ways to see what I can leverage with a custom class versus just 'select t'. thanks

Answer (score 2):

For a single return value you could use:

```
var transactions = (from t in db.Transactions
                    where t.SellingPrice != 0 
                    select t).FirstOrDefault();
```

For an IEnumerable  return:

```
var transactions = (from t in db.Transactions
                    where t.SellingPrice != 0 
                    select t).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var transactions = (from t in db.Transactions
                        select new
                       {
                           t.SellingPrice,
                           t.CommissionPercent,
                           ...,
                           ...,
                           t.Etc...
                       }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new HomeModel // Create a model which have following properties
                        {
                           SellingPrice= x.SellingPrice,  //(where SellingPrice is a HomeModel property)
                           AdCategoryTitle = x.CommissionPercent,
                           ...,
                           ...,
                           ETc... = t.Etc...
                       }).ToList();
```